# how to preserve formatting of html textarea

Tags: javascript, html, editor, textarea

the question is i have a textarea, from which if the text is copied and pasted to a word document it looses all formatings like fonts and colors only plaintext is retained. I am alrewady aware of Ckeditor and nicedit but i am trying to make my own implementattion of such editor .
the question is what should be my approach?
which direction i should start?

Note: i am using javascript

the code is below

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="index.css" type="text/css">
    <style>


    textarea {
    resize: none;
    width: 80%;
    height: 600px;    
        }
#dock{

width: 80%;
height: 61px;



background: rgb(246, 242, 250);

-moz-box-shadow:  2px 0px 4px 0px rgb(128,128,128);
-webkit-box-shadow:  2px 0px 4px 0px rgb(128,128,128);
box-shadow:  2px 0px 4px 0px rgb(128,128,128);

}
.btn {
border:1px solid #495267; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px;border-radius: 3px;font-size:12px;font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block;text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);font-weight:bold; color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: #606c88; background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#606c88), to(#3f4c6b));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #606c88, #3f4c6b);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #606c88, #3f4c6b);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #606c88, #3f4c6b);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #606c88, #3f4c6b);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #606c88, #3f4c6b);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#606c88, endColorstr=#3f4c6b);
}

.btn:hover {
 border:1px solid #363d4c;
 background-color: #4b546a; background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4b546a), to(#2c354b));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4b546a, #2c354b);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4b546a, #2c354b);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4b546a, #2c354b);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4b546a, #2c354b);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4b546a, #2c354b);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#4b546a, endColorstr=#2c354b);
}
#b1{
float:left;
width: 10px;
height: 25px;
line-height: 5px; /* <- changed this */
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-left: 3px;
margin-top: 3px;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body> 
<div id="editor">
        <center>
        <div id="dock">
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="b1" onclick="myFunction()">B</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="b1" onclick="myFunction()"><i>i</i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="b1" onclick="myFunction()">U</button>
        </div>
        <textarea id="textarea-1" rows="20" cols="70"></textarea>
        </center>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use something like [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/) or [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/). The native `<textarea>` element cannot handle fancy scripting.

Comment: the thing is thats what exactly i want to know how does ckeditor or tinymce  hanfdles formatting?whats their approach? so that i can implement it myself

Comment: You are talking about a pretty massive operation to recreate one of these things. My company did it and I'm not sure if it was worth our time. The most common approach (as far as I know) is to catch all the changes into the textarea and use an iframe to display the formatted text. It would be helpful to use your console and debug what is going on with the editor as you make changes to it.

Comment: i am just a student and this is my learning phase and i have my complete summer comming so i thought to take this task as a project so time is not an issue .i know its reinventing a wheel but again its just because of learning not for production environment.

Comment: can you please elaborate your approach in a little more detail

Comment: If you are using chrome, travel to [tinymce.com](http://www.tinymce.com/). Open up your developer tools. Try inspecting the various elements used in the editor on the home page. The documentation on the page might help as well. I'm no expert into how this stuff is created though. Good luck.