# I have a text area, that will have multiple lines of text

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have a text area, that will have multiple lines of text and I need the output to keep all formatting as it is typed in to the text area. How can this be done? Here is how I am creating the text area:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="95%">              
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<b>Status: </b> 
<textarea name="Text2" id="styled"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What output? What formatting?

Comment: I am using the text that is entered in to that textarea to create a text output for an email message that I am sending using CDO.Message.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to maintain the format of the text in `<textarea>` as you requested.

You can achieve maintaining new lines (basically text is wrapped), if some exists in the text.
You have to use "`wrap=Hard`".

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_wrap.asp

Also refer stackoverflow answers, which has more explanation (look into comments also) about retaining format from text in `<textarea>`

[HTML : How to retain formatting in textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806673/html-how-to-retain-formatting-in-textarea)

[how to preserve formatting of html textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375483/how-to-preserve-formatting-of-html-textarea)

Comment: The most important part would be just maintaining the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to do it by exporting the text area to a text file, appending the data, then import it back in using 
    fso.OpenTextFile("C:\file.txt",ForReading).ReadAll  and formatting it using 
    ( html body pre )
Doing it that way I was able to hold my line breaks then I send the information using CDO.Message.

```
Const FOR_APPENDING = 8 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTSO = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:File.txt", FOR_APPENDING)   
objTSO.WriteLine strDT & ":" & vbCrLf & Text2.value & vbCrLf
objTSO.Close()



Sub SendEmail(strSubject, strBody, strBody8, strFrom)

Const ForReading = 1
Dim fso, BodyText
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strMailbox = "Address<Email@email.com>"                                     
' E-Mail address being sent to
strSMTPServer = "SMTP Server"                                           
' Primary SMTP relay server name    
strSMTPPort = 25                                                            
' SMTP Port Number

Set objEmail = CreateObject( "CDO.Message" )
BodyText = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\file.txt",ForReading).ReadAll
With objEmail
.From     = strFrom
.To       = strMailbox
.Subject  = strSubject
.HTMLBody = "<html><body><pre>" & strBody & "<BR>" & BodyText & "<BR>" & 
 strBody8 & "</pre></body></html>"

With .Configuration.Fields
.Item( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing"      ) = 2
.Item( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver"     ) = 
strSMTPServer
.Item( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport" ) = 
strSMTPPort
.Update
End With
.Send                                               ' Send the message!
End With
Set objEmail = Nothing
```